# Jquery CSS animation on scroll not working as expected

Tags: jquery, wordpress, css-animations

Im trying to implement css animations activated on scroll using this tutorial http://codepen.io/benske/full/yJoqz .

The only thing i have amended is the jquery to work in no conflict mode,

my version:

```
   <script>
 jQuery(function() {
 var $window           = $(window),
      win_height_padded = $window.height() * 1.1,
      isTouch           = Modernizr.touch;

  if (isTouch) { $('.revealOnScroll').addClass('animated'); }

  $window.on('scroll', revealOnScroll);

  function revealOnScroll() {
    var scrolled = $window.scrollTop(),
        win_height_padded = $window.height() * 1.1;

    // Showed...
    jQuery(".revealOnScroll:not(.animated)").each(function () {
      var $this     = $(this),
          offsetTop = $this.offset().top;

      if (scrolled + win_height_padded > offsetTop) {
        if ($this.data('timeout')) {
          window.setTimeout(function(){
            $this.addClass('animated ' + $this.data('animation'));
          }, parseInt($this.data('timeout'),10));
        } else {
          $this.addClass('animated ' + $this.data('animation'));
        }
      }
    });
    // Hidden...
   jQuery(".revealOnScroll.animated").each(function (index) {
      var $this     = $(this),
          offsetTop = $this.offset().top;
      if (scrolled + win_height_padded < offsetTop) {
        $(this).removeClass('animated fadeInUp flipInX lightSpeedIn')
      }
    });
  }

  revealOnScroll();
   });
</script>
```

Ive managed to get the animations activating on scroll however each time you scroll up to remove the animation, on scrolling back down sometimes the animations skip to the last few milliseconds or don't play at all.

you can see my attempt at [dev.silverfx.co.uk](http://dev.silverfx.co.uk) it may take a couple off scroll up and down to see but if you compare the smoothness to the tutorial you'll soon see what i mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For making animations on scroll I would strongly suggest using scrollmagic. It's very simple to use and designed especially for this purpose and much more efficient than wow.

ScrollMagic with GSAP (animation engine, much faster than jquery) will allow you to create much more complex animations with little effort.

I did tried your solution on example link you have provided and I was able to recreate the issue only when scrollin very very fast. It was always caused by animation still playing when I hit the animation viewport again.

For it was working just fine.

Here's the scroll magic example, I think you should give it a shoot:

http://janpaepke.github.io/ScrollMagic/examples/advanced/advanced_tweening.html

Comment: thanks @Mkb, I havent seen this before, looks awsome. I think this will do just the ticket!!